# Executing function in select sql in php

Tags: php, sql, function, codeigniter

I have a small question. In PHP I'm using this where clause to fetch some data from my database:

```
id IN (select ticket_id from ticket_follow_up where dbms_lob.instr(remarks,?) <> 0 and ticket_id = id)
```

When I navigate to the site where the code should be executed, I get an error. This is the error message:

```
Error Number:

SELECT id FROM ticket.ticket WHERE (responsible_user IS NULL OR responsible_user=16) AND state NOT IN (SELECT id FROM ticket.state WHERE is_closed=1) AND id IN (select ticket_id from ticket_follow_up where dbms_lob.instr(remarks,'Yolo') <> 0 and ticket_id = id) ORDER BY creation_date DESC

Filename: /var/www/html/models/ticket_model.php

Line Number: 330
```

But if I copy paste the query and execute it in Toad or SQLPlus, I get the right outcome, without any failures. I guess it has something to do with the function dbms_lob.instr I call. But I'm not sure about this.

Anyone has an idea?

It would really help me out.

Kind regards,

Walle

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I didn't have select rights on the table ticket_follow_up. That's why it crashed.